# Send sql email from two select results

Tags: html, sql-server

I need help, I want to ask, I send emails in two SQL tables as a body of the email. However, when the first table has no results, sends a blank email to me, even though the results of the second table exists.

The problem is with @body = @html1

Thank you very much

```
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.views WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[qdatum2]'))
DROP VIEW [dbo].[qdatum2]
GO

-- vytvorenie

CREATE VIEW qdatum2 AS

SELECT(A.Firma) AS FIRMA, A.ID, (A.OBEC) AS OBEC, (A.Ulice) AS Ulica,  A.Obec2 as 'Obec dod.', A.Ulice2 AS 'Ulica dod.',
VP.IDS AS REGION,
CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN F.RelTpFak = 2 THEN -F.Kc2 ELSE F.Kc2 END) AS DECIMAL(36,2)) AS OBRAT, MAX(F.DATUM) AS MAXDATUM, MIN(F.DATUM) AS MINDATUM
FROM (StwPh_35760532_2015.dbo.AD as A INNER JOIN StwPh_35760532_2015.dbo.sVPULpol AS VP ON A.RefVPrRegion = VP.ID) 
inner JOIN StwPh_35760532_2015.dbo.FA AS F ON A.ID = F.RefAD
WHERE DATEADD(MONTH, 6, F.Datum) > GETDATE()
GROUP BY A.ID, a.Firma, A.Obec, A.Ulice, A.Obec2, A.Ulice2, VP.IDS

union all

SELECT(AD.Firma) AS FIRMA, AD.ID, (AD.OBEC) AS OBEC, (AD.Ulice) AS Ulica,  AD.Obec2 as 'Obec dod.', AD.Ulice2 AS 'Ulica dod.',
sVPULpol.IDS AS REGION,
CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN FA.RelTpFak = 2 THEN -FA.Kc2 ELSE FA.Kc2 END) AS DECIMAL(36,2)) AS OBRAT, MAX(FA.DATUM) AS MAXDATUM, MIN(FA.DATUM) AS MINDATUM
FROM (AD INNER JOIN sVPULpol ON AD.RefVPrRegion = sVPULpol.ID) inner JOIN FA ON AD.ID = FA.RefAD
WHERE DATEADD(MONTH, 6, FA.Datum) > GETDATE()
GROUP BY AD.ID, ad.Firma, ad.Obec, ad.Ulice,AD.Obec2,AD.Ulice2, sVPULpol.IDS
go

IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.views WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[qdatum1]'))
DROP VIEW [dbo].[qdatum1]
GO

-- vytvorenie

CREATE VIEW qdatum1 AS

select (AD.Firma) AS FIRMA, AD.ID, (AD.OBEC) AS OBEC, (AD.Ulice) AS Ulica,  AD.Obec2 as 'Obec dod.', AD.Ulice2 AS 'Ulica dod.', qdatum2.REGION,
SUM(qdatum2.OBRAT) as OBRAT, max(qdatum2.MAXDATUM) as MAXDATUM, MIN(qdatum2.MINDATUM) AS MINDATUM
from AD INNER JOIN qdatum2 ON AD.ID = qdatum2.ID

group by ad.id, ad.Firma, ad.Obec, ad.Ulice, ad.Obec2, ad.Ulice2, qdatum2.region
go

IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.views WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[qdatum]'))
DROP VIEW [dbo].[qdatum]
GO

-- vytvorenie

CREATE VIEW qdatum AS

SELECT qDATUM1.*
FROM qdatum1 
WHERE DATEADD(DAY, 30, qdatum1.MAXDATUM) < getdate()
and qdatum1.REGION like '%OR%'
and qdatum1.OBRAT > 50
GO

DECLARE @html varchar(max)

SET @html = '<html>'
+ '<H3><font id="Text" style="color: Green;">PREHLAD AKTIVNYCH ZAKAZNIKOV BEZ ODBERU ZA POSLEDNYCH 30 DNI </H3>'
+ '<table border="1" bordercolor="#3300FF" style="background-color:#DDF8CC" width="70%" cellpadding=3 cellspacing=3>'
+ '<tr><font color="Green"><th>Firma</th><th>Obec</th><th>Ulica</th><th>Obec dod.</th><th>Ulica dod.</th><th>Obrat v € za posledných 6 mesiacov</th><th>Posledna. Faktura</th>
</tr>' +

CAST (( SELECT

   td =  qdatum.FIRMA, ' ',
   td = qdatum.OBEC, ' ',
   td = CASE WHEN qdatum.Ulica IS NULL THEN '''' ELSE qdatum.Ulica END, ' ', 
   td = CASE WHEN qdatum.[Obec dod.] IS NULL THEN '''' ELSE qdatum.[Obec dod.] end , ' ',
   td =  CASE WHEN qdatum.[Ulica dod.] IS NULL THEN '''' ELSE qdatum.[Ulica dod.] END, ' ',
   td =  qdatum.OBRAT, ' ',
   td = CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),qdatum.MAXDATUM, 106) 
from StwPh_35760532_2016.dbo.qdatum 
where qdatum.REGION like '%B1OR%'
order by qdatum.MAXDATUM
            FOR XML PATH ('tr'),ELEMENTS
) AS VARCHAR(MAX))
+
'<table>'

DECLARE @html1 varchar(max)

SET @html1 = '<html>'
+ '<H3><font id="Text" style="color: Green;">PREHLAD KOMUNIKÁCIE SO ZÁKAZNÍKOM REGION B1OR </H3>'
+ '<table border="1" bordercolor="#3300FF" style="background-color:#DDF8CC" width="70%" cellpadding=3 cellspacing=3>'
+ '<tr><font color="Green"><th>Firma</th><th>Obec</th><th>Ulica</th><th>Obec dod.</th><th>Ulica dod.</th><th>Posledna navsteva</th><th>Posledne volanie</th></tr>' +

CAST( (SELECT 
                            td = AD.Firma , ' ',
                            td = AD.Obec, ' ',
                            td = CASE WHEN AD.Ulice IS NULL THEN '''' ELSE AD.Ulice END, ' ',
                            td = CASE WHEN AD.Obec2 IS NULL THEN '''' ELSE AD.Obec2 END, ' ',
                            td = CASE WHEN AD.Ulice2 IS NULL THEN '''' ELSE AD.Ulice2 END, ' ',                          
                            td = CASE WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR (11), AD.VPrnavsteva, 106) IS NULL THEN '''' ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR (11), AD.VPrnavsteva, 106) END, ' ',
                            td = CASE WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), AD.VPrvolane, 106) IS NULL THEN '''' ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), AD.VPrvolane, 106) END
FROM StwPh_35760532_2016.dbo.AD INNER JOIN StwPh_35760532_2016.dbo.sVPULpol ON AD.RefVPrRegion = sVPULpol.ID
WHERE AD.VPrnavsteva < DATEADD(DAY, -30 , GETDATE()) AND AD.VPrvolane < DATEADD(DAY, -30 , GETDATE())
AND AD.RefAD IS NULL
AND sVPULpol.IDS like '%B1OR%'
ORDER BY VPrnavsteva DESC
            FOR XML PATH ('tr'),ELEMENTS
) AS VARCHAR(MAX))
+
'</table>'
+ @html

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
@profile_name = 'LACI_ADMINISTRATOR',
--@recipients = 'emailxx',
@copy_recipients = 'emailxy',
--@blind_copy_recipients = 'emailxxy',
@subject ='B1OR report',
@body = @html1,
@body_format = 'HTML'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
DECLARE @html varchar(max)

SET @html = '<html>'
+ '<H3><font id="Text" style="color: Green;">PREHLAD AKTIVNYCH ZAKAZNIKOV BEZ ODBERU ZA POSLEDNYCH 30 DNI </H3>'
+ '<table border="1" bordercolor="#3300FF" style="background-color:#DDF8CC" width="70%" cellpadding=3 cellspacing=3>'
+ '<tr><font color="Green"><th>Firma</th><th>Obec</th><th>Ulica</th><th>Obec dod.</th><th>Ulica dod.</th><th>Obrat v € za posledných 6 mesiacov</th><th>Posledna. Faktura</th>
</tr>' +

ISNULL(CAST (( SELECT

   td =  qdatum.FIRMA, ' ',
   td = qdatum.OBEC, ' ',
   td = CASE WHEN qdatum.Ulica IS NULL THEN '''' ELSE qdatum.Ulica END, ' ', 
   td = CASE WHEN qdatum.[Obec dod.] IS NULL THEN '''' ELSE qdatum.[Obec dod.] end , ' ',
   td =  CASE WHEN qdatum.[Ulica dod.] IS NULL THEN '''' ELSE qdatum.[Ulica dod.] END, ' ',
   td =  qdatum.OBRAT, ' ',
   td = CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),qdatum.MAXDATUM, 106) 
from StwPh_35760532_2016.dbo.qdatum 
where qdatum.REGION like '%B1OR%'
order by qdatum.MAXDATUM
            FOR XML PATH ('tr'),ELEMENTS
) AS VARCHAR(MAX)), '')
+
'<table>'

DECLARE @html1 varchar(max)

SET @html1 = '<html>'
+ '<H3><font id="Text" style="color: Green;">PREHLAD KOMUNIKÁCIE SO ZÁKAZNÍKOM REGION B1OR </H3>'
+ '<table border="1" bordercolor="#3300FF" style="background-color:#DDF8CC" width="70%" cellpadding=3 cellspacing=3>'
+ '<tr><font color="Green"><th>Firma</th><th>Obec</th><th>Ulica</th><th>Obec dod.</th><th>Ulica dod.</th><th>Posledna navsteva</th><th>Posledne volanie</th></tr>' +

ISNULL(CAST( (SELECT 
                            td = AD.Firma , ' ',
                            td = AD.Obec, ' ',
                            td = CASE WHEN AD.Ulice IS NULL THEN '''' ELSE AD.Ulice END, ' ',
                            td = CASE WHEN AD.Obec2 IS NULL THEN '''' ELSE AD.Obec2 END, ' ',
                            td = CASE WHEN AD.Ulice2 IS NULL THEN '''' ELSE AD.Ulice2 END, ' ',                          
                            td = CASE WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR (11), AD.VPrnavsteva, 106) IS NULL THEN '''' ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR (11), AD.VPrnavsteva, 106) END, ' ',
                            td = CASE WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), AD.VPrvolane, 106) IS NULL THEN '''' ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), AD.VPrvolane, 106) END
FROM StwPh_35760532_2016.dbo.AD INNER JOIN StwPh_35760532_2016.dbo.sVPULpol ON AD.RefVPrRegion = sVPULpol.ID
WHERE AD.VPrnavsteva < DATEADD(DAY, -30 , GETDATE()) AND AD.VPrvolane < DATEADD(DAY, -30 , GETDATE())
AND AD.RefAD IS NULL
AND sVPULpol.IDS like '%B1OR%'
ORDER BY VPrnavsteva DESC
            FOR XML PATH ('tr'),ELEMENTS
) AS VARCHAR(MAX)),'')
+
'</table>'
+ @html

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
@profile_name = 'LACI_ADMINISTRATOR',
--@recipients = 'emailxx',
@copy_recipients = 'emailxy',
--@blind_copy_recipients = 'emailxxy',
@subject ='B1OR report',
@body = @html1,
@body_format = 'HTML'
```

I added ISNULL on your CAST(SELECT) so that your variable will not turn to null if SELECT doesn't return data.